# What is this symbol that looks like a shrimp tempura on a Philips HD9928 air fryer?

Tags: fryer

This question is about a [Philips HD9228 air fryer](https://www.philips.com.my/c-p/HD9228_01/viva-collection-airfryer-with-rapid-air-technology).

What is the 3rd symbol (C in the screenshot) on this air fryer? The manual doesn't say anything about it. I'm assuming it's a shrimp tempura, or a chicken lollipop.

[image]

Symbols:

- A - frozen french fries
- B - raw/thawed french fries
- C - ???
- D - chicken drumstick
- E - spring roll
- F - muffin

Comment: I know you're right for E, but it will always look a **LOT** like two sticks of butter to me.

Comment: As tempura is battered, it would be difficult to make an in air fryer.  You would need something covered in a crumb-like coating, like maybe coconut shrimp.  (and it'd probably be more curly than the pork chop)

Comment: I’m glad SOMEONE asked this question because I’ve always wondered that myself but was just too lazy to ask. Maybe next someone should ask how you’re supposed to cook cupcakes in an air fryer?

Comment: @WesSayeed There is a baking pan accessory for the HD9228. I suppose you put the muffin cups in it. Maybe you might need to use the splatter-proof lid too.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

According to Philips on Twitter, it's a pork chop.

[image: screenshot showing Phillips' response, "Hi there, that's a pork chop. :)"]

[*link to tweet*](https://twitter.com/Philips/status/1322759230953312267)

Comment: Straight from the horse's... urr, pig's mout... well, you know what I mean.

Comment: The next question I suppose is why you would want to fry a pork chop. But then I'm not sure why you'd want to fry a muffin either.

Comment: @AndrewRay I've had fried pork before, it's not at all uncommon, though maybe not in porkchop form.  The muffin though - that's just baffling...

Comment: I was going to guess steak or pork chop. :-) Good to have the actual instructions available.

Comment: @AndrewRay, air fryers don't really fry things, they do sort of a modified baking.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman fried is the only way I ever had pork chops as a kid.  They're wonderful!

Comment: A fried slice of prime rib!.... doesn't that sound just tasty?